# How do I extract a URL within a UITextView in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to use the UITextView delegate method(textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:) to override the default behavior of links in my textView opening in Safari.

I know I should create the webView I want to instantiate and pass the URL to it, but I don't know how to pass the URL to the webView.

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{

//Do something with the URL
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.sourceInformation.text.?];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
WebViewController *sourceWebViewController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewController"];

[sourceWebViewController.webView loadRequest:request];

sourceWebViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

return NO;
```

}

Is there some property on UITextView that hold the URL? I looked at the header file but didn't see one.

If anyone can help, thanks.

Comment: Now, I've never used that particular feature, but what's wrong with the `shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL` parameter? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: There is a `URL` parameter in the method.  I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies. In other words, how does the method know which URL to pass from the textView to the other webViewController?

Comment: Probably because the user tapped it and the text view is consulting you on what to do with it.

Comment: The NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.sourceInformation.text.?];   This creates the URL to pass to the webViewController. I have 12 pages of text in one textView. How do I get the URL to pass?

Comment: @dan ah, yes. long day. I'm simply passing the URL argument to     NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];

Comment: but I'm still missing something in my code. Now the links won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadWebView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1] ;
    return NO;
}

-(void)loadWebView
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.sourceInformation.text.?];
    if([[UIApplicaiton sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
    {
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        WebViewController *sourceWebViewController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewController"];
        [sourceWebViewController.webView loadRequest:request];
        sourceWebViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Can not open the URL, check the URL") ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: so, self.sourceInformation.text (text in textView) would work?

Comment: If you are able to enter into if loop, yes it works.